# How to Remove the Spring Boot default login page when spring security is Used

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I enabled spring security but I see a default login page [image]

I tried removing it by using

```
security.basic.enabled = false
```

in my properties file and also excluding the securityAutoconfiguration class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com"},exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class,SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

but to no avail.

My customSecurityClass does not has no implementation tho, could this be the problem ?

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Comment: @dur  i am using version 1.x

Comment: @dur if i remove my CustomSecurityConfiguration , how do i then implement my own Spring security

Comment: @dur rest endpoints and secondly is securing Rest end point with spring security a good practice?

Comment: @dur i am trying secure all my rest endpoint and normal Urls

Comment: @dur i will prefer OAuth2

Comment: @dur honestly i am new to this security stuff, i have an application that is 90% rest Api calls since it is a single page application. So i dont know what to use, either JWT or Spring security, but i want to make my API end point secure

Answer (score 0):

just create a custom login page, lets say `login.html` than in the `CustomSecurityConfiguration` add

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html");
}
```

Comment: would it still work, since my login is actually an API rest call

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set its authentication to something else rather than formLogin. To do it, just create a bean for the filter chain setting the SecurityFilterChain to be httpBasic or anything else you want.

```
@Configuration
class FilterChainConfig {

@Autowired
lateinit var authenticatorProvider: AuthenticationProvider

@Bean
fun filterChain( http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain { 
    return http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults) // Adding this will remove your formLogin.
        .authorizeHttpRequests { authorize ->
            authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
        } 
        .build()
}
}
```